# queries in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have written the following query and it is giving error Unable to cast object of type

`System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'[ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch]' to type 'ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch'.`

my code is as follows

```
 if (zipcode.Contains(","))//opening of zipcode conatins comma
 {
    do
    {
        zipcode = zipcode.Replace("  ", " ");
        zipcode = zipcode.Replace(", ", ",");

    } while (zipcodecity.Contains("  "));
    char[] separator = new char[] { ',' };
    string[] temparray = zipcode.Split(separator);
    var zipcd = (from u in db.ZipCodes1
                 where u.CityName == temparray[0] && u.StateAbbr == temparray[1] && u.CityType == "D"
                 select new Viewsearch
                 {
                     Zipcode = u.ZIPCode


                 }).Distinct();
    Viewsearch vs = (Viewsearch)zipcd;
    if (zipcd.Count() > 0)
    {
        zipcode = vs.Zipcode;
        locations = "";
    }
    else
    {
        tempStr = "";
        zipcode = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Distinct` method returns an enumerable collection (in your case, and `ObjectQuery<T>`, which may contain more than one element. You can't typecast that directly to an item in the collection, you need to use one of the IEnumerable methods to get it:

```
Viewsearch vs = zipcd.SingleOrDefault();
if ( vs != null )
{
    zipcode = vs.Zipcode;
    locations = String.Empty;
}
else
{
    zipcode = String.Empty;
    tempStr = String.Empty;
}
```

`SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if there is more than one item in the collection; if that's a problem, you can also use `FirstOrDefault` to grab the first item, as one example.

Also, unrelated to your question, but you don't need the temporary array variable for your string separators. The parameter to the Split method is a `params` array so you can just call it like this:

```
string[] temparray = zipcode.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

If it will always exist:

```
 Viewsearch vs = zipcd.First()
```

If not use, and then check for null before using

```
 Viewsearch vs = zipcd.FirstOrDefault()
```

You could also use `Single` if there will always be 1 or None.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the zipcd query with:

```
var cityName = temparray[0];
var stateAbbr = temparray[1];    
Viewsearch vs = new Viewsearch {
    Zipcode = db.ZipCodes1.Where(u.CityName == cityName && u.StateAbbr == stateAbbr && u.CityType == "D").First().ZIPCode 
};
```

Comment: what is u it should be lke this //var zipcd = (from u in db.ZipCodes1
                                    //             where u.CityName == temparray[0] && u.StateAbbr == temparray[1] && u.CityType == "D"
                                    //             select new Viewsearch
                                    //             {
                                    //                 Zipcode = u.ZIPCode


                                    //             }).Distinct();
                                    //Viewsearch vs = (Viewsearch)zipcd.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: it is giving error The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Then save them to variables: var cityname = temparray[0]; var stateAbbt = temparray[1]; ... and use those variables instead in the query